# ASP.NET Core MVC AJAX call to Action method not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am new to AJAX and I am trying to get some data from my controller method into my .js file so I can use that data in my chart.
Everytime I run my project now I get the custom error message: "Error loading data! Please try again."
So that means that it is getting inside the AJAX function, but not successfully. 
Also I dont know how to debug this properly to see where it goes wrong.

My .js code in a sepperate file is the following:

```
var chartData;

$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Account/GetChartData",
    data: "",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        chartData = data.d.toString();
        alert("Data is: " + data.d.toString());
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
    }
}).done(function () {
    //After complete loading data
    drawChart();
});
});
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
public static object[] GetChartData()
    {
        var chartData = new object[2];

        //Manually adding some test data
        chartData[0] = new object[]
        {
            "Day",
            "Detected Asparaguses",
            "String Operations",
            "Successful Sting Operations"
        };
        chartData[1] = new object[]
        {
            "21-09-2018",
            100,
            85,
            80
        };
        return chartData;
    }
```

Comment: You can try putting a debug point in GetChartData method to see whether AJAX request reaches to action. Also, try writing your action method as "public JsonResult GetChartData()" and return line as "return Json(chartData);".

Comment: You specify `dataType: "json",` but you not returing json. Change the method to `[HttpPost] public ActionResult GetChartData()` and use `return  Json(chartData);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes that worked! Now I can see that my breakpoint in GetChartData is getting hit, and the AJAX is succeed. But data.d.toString() is "Undefined" it says. Do you perhaps know if that code is wrong? I just assumed it was right, because I saw it on a tutorial

Comment: `data` in `success: function (data) {` is your model that you returned - but what you are returning really makes no sense (but I do not know what your chart plugin is or what format it expects the data in.

Comment: You're not having any key named `d` in JSON string, therefore `d.toString()` is always undefined. You need to wrap it in key-value pair format if you want to use `d`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Alright, I just removed the .d.toString() and now i see the array that I manually created! Thanks guys!!! <3 If you put it in an answer I will mark it as an solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `dataType: "json"` but your method does not return json, and you would be getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)`. Change the method to return a `JsonResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetChartData() // or `JsonResult`
{
    var chartData = new object[2];
    ....
    return Json(chartData);
}
```

and then `data` in the ajax callback will contain the array of your objects.

Comment: Maybe you can tell me aswel how to pass a parameter into the ajax method and pass that parameter to the controller method? I am using a Html.Actionlink to call the ajax function. (I deleted $(document).ready and created a function with a name)

Comment: Do you mean pass a value to a parameter in your `GetChartData()` method? If so, you use `data: { xxx: someValue }`, and then change the method to `GetChartData( string xxx)` (or `int` or whatever type you want. Note there is no point using `ActionLink()` if you are not redirecting, and you may as well just use `<a href="#" id="xx">Do something</a>` and the `$('#xx').click(function() { ... }`

Comment: I explaned it a bit better here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328239/asp-net-core-mvc-passing-parameter-to-js-function-via-html-actionlink-and-receiv

Comment: Just use `<a href="#" id="xx" data-id="@field.Id">Details</a>` and in the script - `var id = $(this).data('id');` and in the ajax function - `data: { fieldId: id },`

Comment: But when I do that, I can't call my method Field in Account controller, right?

Comment: But you are calling the `GetChartData` method in your ajax  function. Are you trying to call 2 methods? (which wont work because your `ActionLink()` is redirecting - and making the ajax call pointless since you have left that page).

Comment: Yes that is right. I want to call 2 methods. When the Details button is pressed (actionlink) I want to change the view to the Field view AND I want to activate the ajax call. How do I do this in the best way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180043/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-svenmarim).